# How to create users in/for apps

Tags: android, ios, database, authentication

I have a question that probably has a straight forward answer, but I am asking here to make sure.

If I want to develop an app with users (e.g. Snapchat, Wordfeud etc.), how do I do it? Do I have to use a database of some kind? The users will not have much information stored to them, say nothing more than a username and a score collection.

Can I do this without using databases?
And how do I even set up an app for having users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database.
For the simplest, you can set up a MySQL database on any server, and make queries to it.

You can follow this tutorial: http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

You will need a database if you want to implement some functionalities like friendlist and sending messages.

To handle the authentication, Google has built in tools to help you :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in